# What is good practice about models in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to display a washing machine in my Angular app. To do so, I created a `Machine` model:

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export class Machine {
  id: number;
  type: string;
  pricing: string;
  enableDurationSelection: boolean;
  maxDuration: number;
  costPerCycle: number;
  elapsedTime?: number = 0;
  user?: User;
}
```

and a machine user:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName: string;
  balance: number;

  getUsername(): string {
    let username = '';
    if (this.firstName) {
      username += this.firstName[0] + '. ';
    }
    username += this.lastName.toUpperCase();
    return username;
  }
}
```

1. How can I perform duck typing for the `User` model? The
   `getUsername()` property seems to break it.
2. I'd like to add a timer to the machine to display the duration of a
   cycle. I could add `startTimer()` and `stopTimer()` properties to my
   `Machine` model but it needs also extra properties like an
   `Observer` that is not related to the machine data and will break the duck typing too.

What's the recommended way to deal with this situation?

**Edit**

Finally I found the [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer) package on NPM to do it.

Comment: The way my google search result defines duck typing it's done with an interface. What is your definition of duck typing? Perform duck typing, what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: You often want to use an API to get the data. The API returns a JSON that, if the name of the fields match, can be directly typed as a User (duck typing). Of course the API won't give you the getFullname() function but it's well defined by the User class.

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest a concrete type for every possible return type, or use `any` and later filter by the name property. e.g. `this.http.post<any>(url, payload).pipe(map(data => data.name === 'machine'));` if you just need to have duck typed data, which I really would not recommend.

Comment: I can't edit my comment. So here's the command again to filter based on the name property. `this.http.post<any>(url, payload).pipe(map(data => data.filter(item => item.name === 'machine')));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to create object instances using object notation will all the fields and you assume that methods should be added to the created object somehow.

The closest alternative would be to add a constructor to the class that accepts an object containing initial values for fields:

```js
interface MachineOptions {
    id : number;
    type: string;
    ...
}

export class WashingMachine {
    // field declarations here

    public constructor(options: MachineOptions) {
        // copy options to instance's fields here
    }
}


const machine = new WashingMachine({
    id: 1,
    type: 'm-type1',
    ...
})
```

I also suggest avoiding the class as interface implementation here (like `class WashingMachine : IMachineOptions`) so that you can hide implementation details (internal field semantics may differ from options).

**UPD**: if you want to get a ready-to-use machine object from web API service, you can wrap the response from a server somewhere in that service:

```js
class MachineService {
    getMachine(id: number): Observable<WashingMachine> {
         return this.http
             .get(`/machine/${id}`) // edit the API call as needed
             .pipe(map(options => new WashingMachine(options)); // wrapping part
    }
}

class MachineComponent {
   ...
   ngOnInit() {
       // Example of usage
       this.machineService
           .getMachine(1)
           .subscribe(m => m.startTimer());
   }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to do requests to a REST API to get the data with `this.http.post<Machine[]>()` and to add extra feature to the data. For example I do a request to `/laundry/5263/machines` to get machines ID, type and timer duration and add `startTimer()` and `stopTimer()` functions. That way I can get machine's type with `machine.type` and start the timer with `machine.startTimer()`.

Comment: Updated the answer